# IOS Distribution Certificate using Adobe Flash - Error Storage Issue (Mobile Provisioning File) PackageExtractionFailed

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, certificate, software-distribution

I am trying to install an app on my iPhone from my computer using Flash cs6. I had it working before but my p12 expired. My friend on a mac made me a new one. From developer.apple.com I created a new provisioning file. I run the app install and I get this error.

**Error Creating Files.**

**Installation Error: PackageExtractionFailed.
Device Error: please check if there is enough space on the device.**

I have enough space. I think this is an issue with the two files and a combination of many other things. There are just so many options when making the provisioning file that I don't know what ones to choose for DEVELOPMENT.

I am putting all the errors in length in hopes that, when we find the answer, someone will find this in a search and it will help them too. It's very hard to find info on this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Have you included the new p12 file ?

Comment: Yes, I found this video. I used the file they gave in the link, to create a new certificate. It works for now. But I am not content as I have no idea what this did. But the good news is it does work on my phone now. :) Here is the link. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oi6eqa8vtG8

Answer (score 1):

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-Adobes-iPhone-Packager-without-an-Appl/step2/Exporting-the-App/
try with this one, if it work make another provisioning profile

Comment: oh wow, if this works it would be amazing. Looks good. I don't have time to try it now but I will let you know asap when I do. Thanks for the great tip. :)